# Get value of a h4 selector inside multiple selectors in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `ul` list in `HTML` and I am struggling to get the `inner` text of the `li` element. I will simplify a little the example to be easy to understand what I am trying to do.
I have the following `ul` with list items:

```
<ul id="table-history">
    <li class="item">
       <div class="item-row">
           <h4 class="item-title"> A </h4>
       </div>
     </li>

     <li class="item">
       <div class="item-row">
           <h4 class="item-title"> B </h4>
       </div>
     </li>        

     <li class="item">
       <div class="item-row">
           <h4 class="item-title"> C </h4>
       </div>
     </li>
</ul>
```

I have created a click method in javascript that get triggered when a list item is clicked:

```
$("#table-history > li").on("click", function () {

        console.log("Clicked");
});
```

How can I take the text inside the `<h4>` element ? Is there a way how can I make the click on chain `elements`/`views` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use

```
$('h4.item-title' , this).text()
```

```js
$("#table-history > li").on("click", function () {
        
        console.log($('h4.item-title' , this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="table-history">
    <li class="item">
       <div class="item-row">
           <h4 class="item-title"> A </h4>
       </div>
     </li>

     <li class="item">
       <div class="item-row">
           <h4 class="item-title"> B </h4>
       </div>
     </li>        

     <li class="item">
       <div class="item-row">
           <h4 class="item-title"> C </h4>
       </div>
     </li>
</ul>
```

> **Note:**  It will be better to use `.trim()` to avoid white spaces

```
$('h4.item-title' , this).text().trim()
```

Comment: Thank you :) this is the best answer. Going to mark it as an aswer

Answer (score 2):

Try using `text()`:

```
$("#table-history > li").on("click", function () {
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

**EXAMPLE**

```js
$(document).on('click', '.item', function() {
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="table-history">
    <li class="item">
       <div class="item-row">
           <h4 class="item-title"> A </h4>
       </div>
     </li>

     <li class="item">
       <div class="item-row">
           <h4 class="item-title"> B </h4>
       </div>
     </li>        

     <li class="item">
       <div class="item-row">
           <h4 class="item-title"> C </h4>
       </div>
     </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use this

```
$("#table-history > li").on("click", function () {

    console.log($(this).find('h4').text());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this simplest method:

```
$("#table-history > li").on("click", function () {
     alert($(this).text().trim());
});
```

And Your Final [Output](https://jsfiddle.net/hdy33br2/6/)