# how to get value from raw html tag with out id in php

Tags: php, html

hello i have a raw html text getting from curl

```
            <div class="visible-xs-block visible-block">
            <a id="mainUrl" href="https://soroush-app.ir">
                <p class="soroush-color-font"> اگر هنوز 
                    <strong>
                سروش</strong> ر ا
            نصب نکرده اید
            می توانید از اینجا دریافت کنید
                </p>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="soroush-box well">
                    <!--<i class="fa fa-commenting-o"></i>-->
                    <p align="center">
                        <img src="https://cdn111-fs2.soroush-hamrah.ir/static_file/d8/1515067110062YGj5vWE9fuLacRzCnDodFUViOKqgX4p2.thumbnail.png?" width="128" class="img-circle">
                    </p>
                    <h2 align="center">
                        <b>ورزش ۳</b>
                    </h2>
                    <h4 align="center">220,684 عضو</h4>
                    <p align="center">
                        <br />
```

i want to extraxt the int value of this tag

```
<h4 align="center">220,684 عضو</h4>
```

only need to get 220684 
and this h4 tag is the only h4 tag that exists in this raw html

i saw lot of DOMDocument example but they all used id or class name of tag to get 
value  so i will be really thanks full if some one help me how to do this

Comment: How about http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php?

Comment: but this one is for xml ! can i use it for html ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get value of a h4 selector inside multiple selectors in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38565635/get-value-of-a-h4-selector-inside-multiple-selectors-in-javascript)

Comment: Yes, DOMDocument will work on HTML as well.

Comment: tanx very lot @Don'tPanic i could extraxt 220,684 عضو until now . do you have any idea on how i can extract only int value in php ;

Answer (score 1):

taxn to Don't Panic comment i could extract h4 value like this

```
      $dom = new DOMDocument;
      $dom->loadHTML($raw);
      $h4s =$dom->getElementsByTagName('h4');
      $h4 = $h4s[0];
      $count =   $h4->nodeValue;
```

and could extraxt int value using this

```
$count= preg_replace("/[^-0-9]+/", '', $count_string);
```